# How to produce HTML files of file diffs from two directories in Linux

Tags: linux

I haven't quite come across an answer of this sort. I have 2 directories with the same filenames and would like to find the file diff for each set of files to produce HTML files from the result of these diffs. Bare in mind all files have modifications to it.

For example:

dir1  
   file1.txt  
   file2.txt  
   ...so on

dir2  
   file1.txt  
   file2.txt  
   ...so on

The result could look something like this, but the HTML file names really don't matter:  
file1.html  
file2.html  
..so on

How could I go about doing this? I have roughly 100 file diffs, which means 100 HTMLs. I would be very surprised if there was a command for this (hoping there is). So far, I've gathered to use the command vi -d file1 file2, :set diffopt+=iwhite to ignore whitespace, then :TOhtml to produce one HTML file. I'm fairly new to scripting so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a shell script similar to this:

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 100)
do
    diff dir1/file$i.txt dir2/file$i.txt > file$i.html
done
```

Adapt it to your particular needs.